# Error al conectar con Base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos

el problema es el siguiente: Quiero Mandar datos de un pequeño formulario de mi página a una base de datos, pero nisiquiera me deja conectarme con la base de datos....(uso heidisql, por las dudas)
Todo lo que voy a mostrar ahora funciona (lo haré abreviado).

Hice un botón de enviar

```
<form id="formulario" action="enviar.php" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="chequear();">
```

La función "chequear" me permite verificar que el formulario está bien, al estar bien se aplica esto

```
document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
```

La acción de "Formulario" sucede en la página "enviar.php"y ahí es en donde está el problema, sé cómo mandar la información a la base de datos y sé conectarme, pero por alguna razón no me deja, la idea era verificar que me pueda conectar y luego escribir el resto de código, pero al no conectarme, solo escribí la siguiente línea (en la página enviar, y ya verifiqué que no me equivoqué en páginas anteriores)

```
<?php

$conex = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$conex) {
    echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
} else  {
   echo 'Estás conectado';
}
?>
```

Me dice que el problema está en la línea "5" o sea en

```
$conex = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

Según yo, tengo todo bien escrito, por las dudas les dejo la imagen de cómo aparece el error.[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5G99.png)

Comment: El error es por qué seguro tienes un php 7 o superior y ahí solo funcionan MySQLi o pdo dado lo cual tu código es obsoleto entonces considera migrarlo

Comment: No tu usas MySQL, Heidi es solo un gestor de bases de datos

Comment: Soy muy novato en esto, así que perdón pero...Php no es un lenguaje? cómo puede ser que lo tenga si es solo una forma de escribir? si no te molesta aclarame eso por favor, y......cómo lo migro?? (no sé si tiene algo que ver, pero estoy usando heidisql 8.2.0)

Comment: Cómo insisto Heidi no tiene nada que ver, en tu consulta has php -v y te dura la versión, busca sobre PDO para identificar como migrar tu código

Comment: Coincido con @Aprendiz en que debes usar `mysqli` o `PDO`. Además, te falta el nombre de la base de datos en tu cadena de conexión `$conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nombre_base_datos");`

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr conectar correctamente con la base de datos y enviar un "query" a la misma necesitas los siguientes valores:

- DBHost
- DBName
- UserName
- UserPassword

En tu solicitud de conexion solo veo tres, los que intuyo son: el DBHost, el UserName y el UserPassword, todavia no conecta con una base de datos en especifico.

Igual, te recomiendo usar las funciones mysqli que esa que estas utilizando esta en desuso desde hace unos años.

*Añadida la sugerencia*

Si usas PHP 7 mysql_connect no es una funcion reconocida, fue removida.

Para usar mysqli:

Estilo procedimental

```php
<?php
$conx = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

if (!$conx) {
  echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
?>
```

Estilo POO

```php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Si el OP usa PHP 7 entonces está respuesta no es de utilidad más allá de la recomendación que le das

Comment: Que tiene que ver la version de PHP con los parametros incompletos en la funcion?

Comment: Que la función con todo y tú recomendación  no servirá

Comment: Ya, agregado a la respuesta

Comment: @Aprendiz 
Busqué y me informé un poco más.
Es como dijiste, el código no me servía dada la versión de php, al usar mysqli logré mi cometido. Estaba acostumbrado a conectar primero con mysql_connect y luego mysql_select_db, pero no me servía el código, muchas gracias a ti y a todos los que respondieron, saludos.

Comment: En las versiones anteriores de **PHP** la función `mysql_connect()` (cuando existía) permitía ingresar sólo tres (03) parámetros. Entonces, para seleccionar una base de datos tenía que utilizarse `mysql_select_db('base_de_datos')`. Ahora bien, la función `mysqli_connect()` acepta cuatro (04) parámetros, que son: _host_, _usuario_, _contraseña_, _base_de_datos_.

Comment: También puede utilizar `$enlace = new mysqli('host', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'base_de_datos')` para utilizarlo con el paradicta _Programación Orientada a Obtjeto (POO)_. @AugustoM, la información suministrada en estos comentarios la puedes utilizar en tu respuesta si te resultan útiles.